# iOS \t (tab character) not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, uilabel, arabic, right-to-left

When I try to add tab white spaces to my UILabel text in Arabic, it seems not working, while in english it's working ok:

English : (_ means white space)

col1\tcol2\tcol3\t  >>> 
 COL1ــــCOL2ــــCOL3

Arabic
لغة۱\tلغة۲\tلغة۳ >>>

لغة۱لغة۲لغة۳

Comment: It's working. There is a tab character with zero width. Set the arabic string you wrote to UITextField and move cursor on it.

Comment: @Satachito UITextField is input box, I need static label

Comment: hi! its been long time, but You can set UITextField as a static label:
textField.editable = NO;